# WebForms Magento. How to get id for php?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I just installed Webforms on my Magento Web. It works perfect, but I need to go a step further:

I have the modern theme on my Web site. When you go to a product, you see some tabs:

[image]

And I want the WebForm I just created to appear on the second tab. The problem is that I need to call the Webform programatically, not using the regular method for showing the Webform.

Does anybody know how can I call the Webform using PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. To inside a WebForm inside anywhere on the site:

1. Create a block
2. Insert the widget with your WebForm
3. Call your block from your .phtml

In my case, I followed [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/19498/) link to create new tab and insert my block like this: